# How to compare two images in Robot Framework

Tags: html, selenium, automation, html5-canvas, robotframework

I am new in automation and want to automate a site whose back-end in HTML5 and containing canvas element.
I want to compare canvas images with my stored image.
For image comparison I need to use robot framework.
I had tried with "robotframework-imagehorizonlibrary" library but still testcases were failed.
Can any one please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you tried to compare images?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the `RobotAppEyes Library`, which is basically an extended version of `Selenium2` library, and it actually has a keyword named `Compare Images`.

Use it as the following:

`Compare Image <path, imagename=None, ignore_mismatch=False, includeEyesLog=False, httpDebugLog=False>`

see details here: http://navinet.github.io/Robot-AppEyes/RobotAppEyes-KeywordDocumentation.html

Comment: I cannot see `Compare Images` keyword in the linked page.

Comment: @Alex.S true, sorry, fixed the link in the answer.

Comment: I'm not an author but I think this is a good tutorial, https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/09/robot-framework-compare-images-screenshots/