# how to make screenshot with RIDE robotframework

Tags: selenium, bdd, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I'm making a RIDE test projet to exécute the following test:
- open chrome browser at a URL than to make a screen shot to compare it with an other image.

here is the test cass:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
TC1
    [Documentation]    Ouvrir extremeexcelsolutions.weebly.com \ \ sur chrome et vérifier les éléments.
    Open Browser    https://extremeexcelsolutions.weebly.com    chrome
    Click Element    xpath=//li[@id='pg224152549677137323']
    Sleep    10s
    ${text}=    Get Text    xpath=//*[@id="wsite-content"]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]
    Log    ${text}
CT2
    Library    Screenshot
```

I'm wonderng how to make the scren shot. 
thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using [Capture page screenshot](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Capture%20Page%20Screenshot)? By the way, RIDE is just an IDE, it is a separate product from robot. It can't take screenshots, it merely lets you edit tests. It is the robot test that takes the screenshot, and for that it doesn't need RIDE.

Comment: thank you, I could make the screen shot with " Take screenshot". Now, I wonder how to comapre this image with an other image ?

Comment: E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40020984/how-to-compare-two-images-in-robot-framework

Comment: thank infinity, Well done,

Comment: @BryanOakley : can I execute .py file through cmd ?

Comment: @SalahLeila: I don't know what you mean by "through cmd". You can write keywords in python, and since they are in python, they can do anything that python is capable of doing.

Comment: thank you  a lot :)